# ios convert string "5 hours 10 min" to into integer hours and min

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying get hours and min in integer variable from string **"5 hours 10 min"**.can anyone give me solution for this.

```
NSString *duration =@"5 hours 10 min";

int hours = 5
int min = 10
```

Comment: Do You want this in two different variables?

Comment: What did you try? Did you try `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: @  Er.Shreyansh Shah Yes

Comment: is this format is fix?

Comment: can you show me acutel condition

Answer (score 7):

Please try following code for retrieve int value.

```
@try {
    NSString *myString = @"5 hours 10 min";
    NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]
                        ];
    int hoursValue = 0, minuteValue = 0;
    hoursValue = [[myWords objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    if([myWords count] > 2) {
        minuteValue = [[myWords objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
    }

    NSLog(@"hours %d and Minute %d",hoursValue,minuteValue);
 }
 @catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
 }
```

Comment: please put this code in try catch other wise if your formate change it may crash your application

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    @try
    {
           NSString *myString = @"5 hours 10 min";
           NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
           int hoursValue = 0, minuteValue = 0;
           if ([myWords count] == 4)
           {
                hoursValue = [[myWords objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
                minuteValue = [[myWords objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

           }
           else if([myWords count] == 2)
           {
                if([[myWords objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"hours"] == yes)
                {
                    hoursValue = [[myWords objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
                }
                else
                {
                    minuteValue = [[myWords objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
                }
           }   
           NSLog(@"hours %d and Minute %d",hoursValue,minuteValue);
    }
    @catch(Exception *exception
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSDateFormatter to convert string1 into an NSDate, then get the required NSDateComponents:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"<Date format>"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

Learn more [here](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int hr,mins;
NSString *str=@"5 hours 10 min";
NSArray *firstWords = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
if (([[firstWords objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"hours"]||[[firstWords objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"hr"] ) &&([[firstWords objectAtIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"minutes"]||[[firstWords objectAtIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"min"])) {
    hr=(int)[[firstWords objectAtIndex:0]integerValue];
    mins=(int)[[firstWords objectAtIndex:2]integerValue];
    if (mins > 60) {
        hr+=mins/60;
        mins    =mins%60;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
{

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60; 
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60; 
    int hours = totalSeconds / 3600; 

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds]; 
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with your answer. It's doesn't belong the question.

Comment: i know but its also good way of HH:MM:SS may be that why i give ans so sory